# How do I use tensor field data with Mayavi for e.g. HyperStreamLine or TensorGlyp visualization?

Tags: python, vtk, tensor, mayavi

I have rank-2 tensor fields I'm trying to visualize in various ways using Mayavi/Mlab. While visualizing the component vectors works okay, I'd like to try and visualize them as tensor glyphs and using hyper streamlines, which there is a Mayavi module for. However, I just can't work out how I'm supposed to get from having my data as a numpy array to actually visualizing the tensor glyphs and the documentation doesn't provide any explanation of how to do this despite repeatedly asserting support for the visualization of tensor data.

Also, any suggestions for other modules for visualization are welcome. I've found Paraview to be too slow for my large fields in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using `Mayavi` visualize tensor fields.
Here is the [script](https://github.com/goballooning/show).

The tensor data is saved in `MAT` format from `Matlab` and converted into `VTK` file in `Python` by `pyvtk`.

The `VTK` format tensor field is for the visualization.
In Mayavi, we can choose a few glyph types, but there is no built-in superquadric tensor glyph.